# How do I fix a major margin issue programming in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, margin

After searching just about everywhere and validating my code a few times (and fixing the mistakes) I am at a loss as to what to do. I started programming this layout in firefox and everything looked perfect then went to check out Chrome and make sure it was ok and low and behold, Chrome screwed it up.

The site is here: http://semperfiwebdesign.com/slipstick/ The problem is with the margins on the footer and footer_top classes.

And I wrote down the code differences for the footer margins and they are stupidly big. Below is the CSS of the original:

```
.footer_top {
float: right;
margin-right: -26px;
margin-top: 69px;}

.footerlinks {
float: right;
margin-right: 120px; }

#text-14 { 
float: right;
margin-right: -25px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: -69px;

}
```

They run in the order they appear with the footer. So footer_top is the box with the top and bottom border, footer links is the paragraph of non working links and finally #text-14 is the "ad" image below the links. I apologize for the weird class names but wordpress gave me a lot of them.

Now seeing that above here is what I figured out using firebug in Chrome to what Chrome wants the fix to be:

```
#text-14 {
margin-top: -190px; }

.footerlinks {
margin-top: -279px; }

.footer_top { 
 margin-top: -422px;}
```

Obviously this is a little absurd and I can't place these numbers into the real style sheet without truly messing up the entire layout.

I have literally searched just about everywhere and I'm at my wits end. I have no idea where to go with this. I would post the entire CSS but since it's wordpress site it's a little long. So if you need to see anything else please ask and I will post it.

Thank You
Megan

Comment: try adding clear:both; to footer?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I did go back and put the right margin in for firefox so the footer looks "ok" there but horrible in chrome. Thanks though for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

set #container -> position: relative;

```
#primary {
    background-color: #002E5B;
    color: white;
    /*float: left;*/
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    /*margin-left: -685px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    min-height: 2500px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 168px;
}
```

and remove all references to #primary in 3c-c-fixed.css

Hope this helps